# Views pager not rendered for teasers with comments

Tags: 7, views, comments, paging

I have a views which displays teasers. Pager is also set.

When comments in teasers is enabled pager doesn't show up, however it does when comments are turned off.

I cannot figure out what the issue might be, please anybody any clue to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to give your pager another "Pager ID" (in the pager options on the view). Try to enter a number bigger than 0.

Comment: If you display the content's comment, you have to enter a "page ID" bigger than how much post you display.